# Extract only <string>/<string> or <string> after specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex that would extract specific portion of the string in nice manner.
I can receive strings that look like this:

- UserA Pending Merge hotfix/taskA to do
- UserB Pending Merge feature/taskC_expansion done
- UserC Pending Merge to do
- UserD Pending Merge hotfix to do

The string after Pending Merge is basically a branch name.

How do i extract the branch name after the Pending Merge word so that it also works for cases where the string is not / and only "hotfix"?

*I can handle the cases where after Pending Merge there is no branch name but if regex for all exists that would be great*.

I tried: 
**[^pending merge].(\w*)** the first word is being matched together with "to". 
**pending merge(.\w+\W+\w+)** but in case of "pending merge hotfix to do" it matches "hotfix to"

Comment: Try `/pending merge\s*(.*?)\s*(?:to do|done)/i`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/d18sHg/1)

Comment: this solves it thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/pending merge\s*(.*?)\s*(?:to do|done)/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d18sHg/1).

**Details**

- `pending merge` - a literal substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:to do|done)` - either `to do` or `done`.

[image]

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['UserA Pending Merge hotfix/taskA to do',
'UserB Pending Merge feature/taskC_expansion done',
'UserC Pending Merge to do',
'UserD Pending Merge hotfix to do'];
var regex = /pending merge\s*(.*?)\s*(?:to do|done)/i;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s);
  var m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log("FOUND: ", m[1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex,

```
Pending Merge\s+(\S+\/\S+|hotfix\b)
```

And capture your branch from group1

The strings that don't have a string of this format `string1/string2` will not match and I hope this is what you expect.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8UrSrk/2)**

```js
var arr = ['UserA Pending Merge hotfix/taskA to do','UserB Pending Merge feature/taskC_expansion done','UserC Pending Merge to do','UserD Pending Merge hotfix to do']

for (s of arr) {
  var m = /Pending Merge\s+(\S+\/\S+|hotfix\b)/i.exec(s)
  if (m != null) {
   console.log(s + " --> " +/Pending Merge\s+(\S+\/\S+|hotfix\b)/i.exec(s)[1])
  } else {
    console.log('No branch found')
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry maybe i should have explained it in clear way that also in the case where there is only "hotfix" it should match it.

Comment: @Arin: Ok, very simple to handle. Just few moments. If string is not of format `string1/string2` then you only want to match `hotfix`? or something more around it? Can you add this sample and expected behavior in your post please?

Comment: @Arin: Updated to capture hotfix. Let me know if that works fine and also let me know if you have any other logic of capturing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

[This simple RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/r3xj6i/1) might help you to do so:

```
User[A-Z] Pending Merge\s(.+)
```

[image]

It would simply create a left boundary in using:

```
User[A-Z] Pending Merge\s
```

and extract everything after using this capturing group `(.+)`.

You can add additional boundary to this group, if you wish.

```
(User[A-Z]{1} Pending Merge\s)(.+|)(?:to\sdo|done)
```

[image]

Then, you might simplify it to something similar to [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/LFURxh/1):

```
User[A-Z]{1} Pending Merge\s(.+|)(to\sdo|done)
```

[image]

and you might call it using <kbd>$1</kbd>, which is the first capturing group with your desired target.